# PHP instead of <form> in HTML to send a form from a script and stay on the redirected page?

Tags: php, html, post, curl, paypal

Right now I have this code in my form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_BLANK" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@********.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="SE">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Premium Membership">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $session_user_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.80">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="SEK">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://*******.com/eta/ipn.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://********.com/purchase/thanks">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://*******.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

But the problem is that I need to grab these values, make some changes in my other file `functions.php` and then go to the `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` in form action, probably using PHP to create a form and submit it (JavaScript is not an option in my case).

So, instead of:
`<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_BLANK" method="post">` I will have:

`<form role="sendit" method="POST">` and it will be grabbed if submitted by my code in functions.php (I am using Wordpress) like:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) && isset( $_POST['post_nonce_field'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce' ) ) {

    // grab values from hidden input fields
    $pp_cmd      = $_POST['cmd'];
    $pp_business = $_POST['business'];
    ...

    // do some internal wordpress stuff with grabbed data for statistical purposes etc.

    // and after that redirect using <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_BLANK" method="post">
    // probably to recreate the form and submit it using php and stay on PayPal site
    ??? what code here ???
}
```

I can grab the values from the post in my functions.php and storred them in variables like e.g. `$pp_cmd, $pp_business`. The problem is that I need somehow use all these variables and send them as input hidden and as form post method to `action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"` and stay on that page to continue on PayPal page as if I just use the default form with action to paypal page.

How to do that?

Could that be done via a straight PHP or PHP with cURL? If yes, could you provide some basic code including at least the two first hidden inputs, so I can finish it by myself?

**UPDATE: Using AJAX is not an option in my position. The script has to work without using JavaScript too. I am looking for a PHP solution of this problem.**

Comment: why dont you onsubmit catch that no OK tag is present, prevent default  and ajax the form to your editing script. Return the updated data (JSON format is good) and update the form with new data and set the OK tag, then submit the form. OR on the processing page re-create the form, with new data, and auto submit it (to paypal)

Comment: @Waygood This is not an option in my position. It has to be working even if the javascript is turned off.

Comment: updated suggestion to submit to your own script then auto submit new form to paypal (for non-javascript you'll need to change the submit button to something like -> redirect to paypal)

Comment: @Waygood Could you please add an answer and explain how to autosubmit a form with the grabbed values using php? Because that's exactly what I am asking in my question ;) It should be in the part `??? what code here ???` in my functions.php

Comment: @Waygood Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Maybe [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304453/submit-paypal-form-update-database-at-same-time ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304453/submit-paypal-form-update-database-at-same-time ) could help you :). I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but there might be some useful answers.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do that using cURL (PHP) like the answer from Ben Miller, but the problem is that the function doesn't redirect me to paypal, but it stays on the same page ;(

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Try using the Paypal API - answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991534/uploading-custom-cart-to-paypal-from-php-page-using-post which means submitting the order to paypal with curl (to get the token in the response), then redirecting to paypal with `header("Location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=XXXXXXX"); exit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
function curl_post($url, array $post = NULL, array $options = array())
{
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post)
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
    if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch))
    {
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
curl_post("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr",$_POST);
```

**Update**: changed CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 0. OP wanted to navigate to the paypal page, not just post.

Comment: ;( it doesn't redirect to `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`. It reloads and stays on the same page as the form ;(. Why is that?

Comment: I tried to add exit(); after `curl_post("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr",$_POST);` so it is `curl_post("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr",$_POST); exit();` but now it is white screen and still on the same page as my form. No redirect happened, just the screen is wwhite because of exit(); Any idea why the redirect to paypal url is not working? I have tried different url and still it's not working ;(. How to redirect the browser to the new URL with post information?

Comment: There have to be something that is blocking the redirect. Do you have any idea what could that be?

Comment: Change CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 0